# Adding columns with add_to_class()?

Tags: django

It appears that add_to_class() https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L218 doesn't actually add a column, but adds a field to the _meta member init.py#L249">https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py#L249. How come those fields shown up as columns in phpmyadmin though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `syncdb` or if it's an existing table, you'll need to create a migration with [South](http://south.aeracode.org/), or manually alter the table yourself to match the model changes introduced by `add_to_class`.